# iFrame not challenging for credentials

Tags: html, ios, cordova, authentication

I'm trying to create a phonegap app which simply holds either `img` tags or `iframes`, all of which come from a number of different servers on our network.

The current challenge I'm facing is, when you navigate to, for example, `http://my-intranet-domain/image.png` in the browser, you are given a login dialog to enter your active directory credentials; when you put this as `<img src="http://my-intranet-domain/image.png" />` in the phonegap app (or even Chrome and Safari on a macbook), you simply get 401 Errors (no challenge for credentials).

How can I:

1. Challenge for usernames and passwords in this situation

and, possibly:

2. After you get the username and password, remember this so you don't have to ask again (there are a number of different servers these images/iframes may come from, but they're all on our domain -- if you have to authenticate, you should only authenticate once).

Answer (score 0):

The webviews don't present a dialog by default. You may want to look into [cordova-plugin-auth-dialog](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/cordova-plugin-auth-dialog) which enables this behavior for Cordova apps. It can persist credentials for the session and on iOS it can persist them forever.